# How to get the TimePicker after the TimePickerDialog pop up

Tags: android, testing, timepicker

I'm working on the android automatic test, and try to test the alarmclock app in the android. I want to get the TimePicker after the TimePickerDialog pop up, then  we can use it to invoke the methods 'setCurrentHour(...)' and 'setCurrentMinute()' to set the alarm time programmatically instead of sending the key event so many times.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

     mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
     mMinute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


     TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mActivity, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);

     private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
         public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

             mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
         mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
         SimpleDateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
         String time = mSDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {

        super(context, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
        try {
            Class<?> superClass = getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field TimePickerField = superClass.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
            TimePickerField.setAccessible(true);
            TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) TimePickerField.get(this);
            timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return currentHour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return currentMinute;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        super.onTimeChanged(view, hourOfDay, minute);
        currentHour = hourOfDay;
        currentMinute = minute;
    }

    private int currentHour;
    private int currentMinute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `onTimeChanged` fires at first time, save the View passed in the method. That view will be  the reference to TimePicker.

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not describe the problem clearly. We can not touch the source code of the alarmclock app in the android, but just test it...